# Advice on SQL-Server Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I'm looking to improve this query I wrote for a small web application in ASP.NET 4.0 using SQL-Server 2005. This application will allow the user to search by Product ID and have it return the following information:

- Highest Purchase Price + Most Recent Date of purchase @ this price
- Lowest Purchase Price + Most Recent Date of purchase @ this price
- Most Recent Purchase Price + Date
- Average Purchase Price (optional, i thought this might improve the usefulness of the app)

Here is the structure of the Products table (I'm only including relevant columns, this is a DB already in production and these are non-pk columns)

- product_id (nvarchar(20))
- price (decimal(19,2))
- pDate (datetime)

Before I put down the query I have so far I just want to say that I can get this information easily through multiple queries, so if this is the best practice then disregard improving the query, but I was aiming to minimize the number of queries needed to get all needed information.

What I have so far: (Note: There are rows with price = 0 so I ignored those in the bottom select looking for the MIN price)

```
SELECT price, MAX(pDate)
FROM Products
WHERE product_id = @product_id AND
     (price = (SELECT MAX(price)
               FROM Products
               WHERE product_id =@product_id) OR
      price = (SELECT MIN(price)
               FROM Products
               WHERE product_id = @product_id AND price > 0))
GROUP BY price
```

Now this is returning 2 rows:

- first = the lowest price + date
- second row = high price + date

What I would like ideally is to have a query return 1 row with all the needed information stated above if possible, as it would simplify displaying the information in ASP for me. And like I said earlier, if multiple queries is the be approach then no need to re-write a complex query here.

*Edit*

Here is some sample data

[image: Sample Data]

Desired query results: (ignore the format as I typed this in excel)

[image]

Here is the query I will be using thanks to Ken Benson:

```
SELECT TOP 1 prod.product_id,
   minp.price AS minprice, minp.pDate as minlastdate,
   maxp.price AS maxprice, maxp.pDate as maxlastdate,
   ag.price AS averageprice
FROM products AS prod
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lmd.product_id,max(lmd.pDate) as pDate,mn.price FROM products as lmd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, min(price) AS price from products WHERE price > 0 group by product_id) as mn ON lmd.product_id=mn.product_id AND lmd.price=mn.price
                  group by lmd.product_id,mn.price ) AS minp ON minp.product_id=prod.product_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lxd.product_id,max(lxd.pDate) as pDate,mx.price FROM products as lxd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, max(price) AS price from products group by product_id) as mx ON lxd.product_id=mx.product_id AND lxd.price=mx.price
              group by lxd.product_id,mx.price ) AS maxp ON maxp.product_id=prod.product_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id,avg(price) as price FROM products WHERE price > 0 GROUP BY product_id) AS ag ON ag.product_id=prod.product_id
WHERE prod.product_id=@product_id
```

Comment: can you post some sample data for each table as well as the expected result?

Comment: Random DB notes (yes, I know this is currently in production): Good for you for using `Decimal` to store money (as opposed to `float` or `real`) - unfortunately the recommendation is usually to store _4_ decimal places...  Also, don't label columns with their datatype (especially if this may change to a related type), make it obvious by the column name - so, `pDate` should probably be `pricedOn` or `priceChangedAt` or similar.

Comment: @bluefeet - added sample data and desired results like you asked

Comment: @X-Zero - Thanks for the DB pointers...The actual column names are quite different and some don't even make sense, I just renamed them here for clarity sakes, but I'll keep in mind what you said about pDate vs something more meaningful like purchaseDate. Also the columns name don't include the data type, I just wasn't sure the best way to show the table structure here. This database is quite poorly designed but nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do a couple of joins back to the table ...

```
Select product_id, min.price, min.pDate, max.price, max.pDate
FROM products as p
LEFT JOIN (Select Min(price), pDate, product_id FROM products GROUP BY product_id) 
   as min on min.product_id=p.product_id
LEFT JOIN (Select max(price), pDate, product_id FROM products GROUP BY product_id) 
   as max on max.product_id=p.product_id
Where p.product_id = @product_id
```

This second bit of code should produce desired results....

```
SELECT prod.product_id,
   minp.price AS minprice, minp.pDate as minlastdate,
   maxp.price AS maxprice, maxp.pDate as maxlastdate,
   ag.price AS averageprice
FROM products AS prod
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT lmd.product_id,max(lmd.pDate) as pDate,mn.price FROM products as lmd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, min(price) AS price from products group by product_id) as mn ON lmd.product_id=mn.product_id
                  group by lmd.product_id,mn.price ) AS minp ON minp.product_id=prod.product_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT lxd.product_id,max(lxd.pDate) as pDate,mx.price FROM products as lxd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, max(price) AS price from products group by product_id) as mx ON lxd.product_id=mx.product_id
                  group by lxd.product_id,mx.price ) AS maxp ON maxp.product_id=prod.product_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id,avg(price) as price FROM products GROUP BY product_id) AS ag ON ag.product_id=prod.product_id
WHERE prod.product_id=1
LIMIT 1
```

Yep - left out an 'and' condition:

```
SELECT TOP 1
 prod.product_id,
   minp.price AS minprice, minp.pDate as minlastdate,
   maxp.price AS maxprice, maxp.pDate as maxlastdate,
   ag.price AS averageprice
FROM products AS prod
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT lmd.product_id,max(lmd.pDate) as pDate,mn.price FROM products as lmd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, min(price) AS price from products group by product_id) as mn ON lmd.product_id=mn.product_id **AND lmd.price=mn.price**
                  group by lmd.product_id,mn.price ) AS minp ON minp.product_id=prod.product_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT lxd.product_id,max(lxd.pDate) as pDate,mx.price FROM products as lxd INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT product_id, max(price) AS price from products group by product_id) as mx ON lxd.product_id=mx.product_id AND **lxd.price=mx.price**
                  group by lxd.product_id,mx.price ) AS maxp ON maxp.product_id=prod.product_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id,avg(price) as price FROM products GROUP BY product_id) AS ag ON ag.product_id=prod.product_id
WHERE prod.product_id=@product_id
```

Comment: Not going to work, for two reasons: 1) To my knowledge, only mySQL supports including non-grouped non-aggregate columns in a result set, and this is SQL Server. 2) Even in mySQL, those the non-aggregate columns are chosen from _any_ of the rows - that is, `pDate` _may_ not be the date you're expecting (and you won't be able to tell, either).

Comment: You are right. The sub-queries would have to be changed to make this work.

Comment: I don't have an MS-SQL instance available to test - but, this (as the sub-query) would work in PostgreSQL: `SELECT product_id,max(price),max("pDate") from products group by product_id`

Comment: If you lack a server instance, [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) can help (although it doesn't have a SQL Server 2005 instance).  Also, that statement isn't going to return the results you expect, as the returned price most likely will **not** match the returned date (it returns the maximum price, with the most recent change, regardless of whether this matches reality).

Comment: Dang it - you are right, X-Zero. I didn't include enough records in sample database to demonstrate that fact.

Comment: I think I have it, now ... :)

Comment: @KenBenson -  Really great job on this query, I just needed to tweak a couple things to get it complete. Firstly, LIMIT doesn't work in SQL-Server but I mimicked it using TOP: "SELECT TOP 1 prod.product_id, ...."  Secondly, I need to filter out prices that equal 0 (Don't ask me why they're their) so I added "where list_per_price > 0" in the third SELECT...Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @KenBenson - I spoke too soon, guess cause I was excited at your awesome query but their is one last issue. Both dates: minlastdate and maxlastdate are returning the most recent date, not necessarily correlating to the min/max prices.

Comment: Indeed ... check the third set ... just needed an additional 'AND' condition in the sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a combination of ranking functions and conditional aggregations:

```
select product_id, 
       max(case when seqnum_hi = 1 then price end) as highPrice,
       max(case when seqnum_hi = 1 then pdate end) as highPrice_date
       max(case when seqnum_low = 1 then price end) as lowPrice,
       max(case when seqnum_low = 1 then pdate end) as lowPrice_date,
       max(case when seqnum_rec = 1 then price end) as recentPrice,
       max(case when seqnum_rec = 1 then pdate end) as recentPrice_date,
       avg(price) as avg_price
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by price asc) as seqnum_low,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by price desc) as seqnum_hi,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by pdate desc) as seqnum_rec
      from price
      where product_id = @product_id
group by product_id
```

The seguence numbers identify the rows with the particular attributes you care about (high price, low price, most recent).  The conditional max then just selects information from those rows.

Comment: `order by desc desc`?  And isn't 'date' a reserved word?  And you're missing the closing paren after `@product_id`.

Comment: Yes, "date" is a reserved word.  I thought that was the name given in the question, but I rechecked and it is pdate.  Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get what you want. It's pretty long, but is readable so should be easily modified by anyone who needs to:

```
;WITH CTE_MaxPrice AS
(
  SELECT product_id, MAX(P.price) AS MaxPrice
  FROM Products P
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING product_id = @product_id
),
CTE_MinPrice AS
(
  SELECT product_id, MIN(P.price) AS MinPrice
  FROM Products P
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING product_id = @product_id 
),
CTE_MaxPriceDate AS
(
  SELECT P.product_id, MAX(P.pDate) AS MaxDate
  FROM Products P
  INNER JOIN CTE_MaxPrice MaxP ON P.product_id = MaxP.product_id 
                               AND P.price = MaxP.MaxPrice
  GROUP BY P.product_id
),
CTE_MinPriceDate AS
(
  SELECT P.product_id, MAX(P.pDate) AS MinDate
  FROM Products P
  INNER JOIN CTE_MinPrice MinP ON P.product_id = MinP.product_id 
                               AND P.price = MinP.MinPrice
  GROUP BY P.product_id
)
SELECT MaxP.MaxPrice, MaxPD.MaxDate, 
       MinP.MinPrice, MinPD.MinDate, 
       RP.price AS RecentPrice, MAX(RP.pDate) AS RecentDate, 
       AVG(AP.price) AS AveragePrice 
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN CTE_MaxPrice MaxP ON P.product_id = MaxP.product_id
INNER JOIN CTE_MinPrice MinP ON P.product_id = MinP.product_id 
                             AND MinP.MinPrice > 0
INNER JOIN CTE_MaxPriceDate MaxPD ON P.product_id = MaxPD.product_id
INNER JOIN CTE_MinPriceDate MinPD ON P.product_id = MinPD.product_id
INNER JOIN Products RP ON P.product_id = RP.product_id
INNER JOIN Products AP ON P.product_id = AP.product_id
GROUP BY MaxP.MaxPrice, MaxPD.MaxDate, 
MinP.MinPrice, MinPD.MinDate, RP.price
HAVING P.product_id = @product_id
```

Comment: `HAVING product_id = @product_id`?  Why not in the `WHERE` clause instead (which may make a performance difference, if SQL Server doesn't auto-commute the value)?  You should also be able to collect the maximum and minimum price in the same CTE, which will eliminate a reference.  You can also 'pass through' the maximum/minimum prices  in the 'latest' dated change.  The comparison for prices `> 0` should be in the `MinPrice` CTE (or that final join may return no rows).  This of course is assuming that you're deliberately attempting to avoid using `ROW_NUMBER()` for those RDBMSs that lack it.

Comment: @Alex Tyman - Tried your solution but switched the HAVING statements to WHEREs (like X-Zero suggested) but I am getting 0 results...There is a warning "Null value is eliminated by a n aggregate or other SET operation" ...gonna keep tinkering with it but any other thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Well since there have been three attempts to answer, and none have worked quite how you want, I'll tell you how I would do it - and this assumes you can use a stored procedure and also assumes that the product table is not so huge that multiple seperate queries would be a problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc AS

  DECLARE @Price1 money
  DECLARE @Date1 smalldatetime

  DECLARE @Price2 money
  DECLARE @Date2 smalldatetime

  DECLARE @Price3 money
  DECLARE @Date3 smalldatetime

  DECLARE @Price4 money

  SELECT @Price1 = MAX(Price) FROM Products
  SELECT @Date1 = MAX(pDate) FROM Products WHERE Price=@Price1

  SELECT @Price2 = Min(Price) FROM Products WHERE Price >0
  SELECT @Date2 = MAX(pDate) FROM Products WHERE Price=@Price2

  SELECT @Date3 = Max(pDate) FROM Products
  SELECT @Price3 = MAX(Price) FROM Products WHERE pDate=@Date3 --max in case there are more than one purchases with the same date.

  SELECT @Price4 = AVG(Price) FROM Products WHERE Price>0

  SELECT @Price1 As MaxPrice, 
         @Date1 As MaxPriceDate,
         @Price2 As LowPrice, 
         @Date2 As LowPriceDate,
         @Price4 As AveragePrice,
         @Price3 As RecentPrice,
         @Price3 As RecentPriceDate
GO
```

Forgive any typographical errors, I didn't test this, but if you can use stored procedures, this will work.

So this is not much different than doing your multiple queries from the client, but should perform better putting them all into a single SP. You could also cut the number of queries down a bit by using some of the code from your other answers, but I have left it this way for clarity.